# Android Support Toolbar: Resizing won't realign menu items

Tags: android, android-support-library

I try to resize the Android Support Toolbar of my `Activity` on orientation change as it is too big in landscape mode. It's not automatically resized as I'm using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

on my activity and thus the activity won't be recreated.
The toolbar XML is like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

in my `onConfigurationChanged()` I'm resizing the toolbar e.g. like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar).setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 114));
```

The result is not as expected. The menu items, which are populated using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` and the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` aren't correctly vertically aligned and neither is the navigation icon (`toolbar.setNavigationIcon(...)`:

[image]

Anyone know of a better way to resize the toolbar or do I need to use workarounds like removing and readding the toolbar to the view stack?

Comment: Can you try changing this `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` ?

Comment: @YeLinAung that can't work. As stated, the toolbar height isn't automatically changed on rotation, so setting it to wrap_content won't change anything, too.

Comment: Have you tried, yet ?

Comment: I opened up a bugreport: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `setMinimumHeight` for toolbar and it will work.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toolbar tb = getActionBarToolbar();
    if (tb != null) {
        int size = UIUtils.calculateActionBarSize(this);
        tb.setMinimumHeight(size);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = tb.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = size;
        tb.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```