# Android Support Library Toolbar not resizing on orientation change

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have my toolbar declared like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

On orientation change its height remains the same (despite that fonts change size and widgets inside rearrange upwards).

How can I fix this so it behaves properly, like an Action Bar?

Comment: Try removing the `minHeight`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Doesn't help.

Comment: When you say, "resize", it should be smaller on Landscape?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes. Yet it remains exactly the same size.

Comment: I have heard of this but it should be naturally apart of `Toolbar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Support Toolbar: Resizing won't realign menu items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970676/android-support-toolbar-resizing-wont-realign-menu-items)

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem:

```
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```